# Dynamically changing onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

How do i change onclick method of button dynamically.?

I have two methods ,success of one method i want to set other method ..just as shifting on success of one button

Comment: Please include html and jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery, you would use `$.on` and `$.off` to bind and unbind events.

If you had attached your handler like this:

```
$("#foo").on("click", function(e) {
  // event handler
});
```

You could remove that handler and add another like this:

```
$("#foo")
  .off("click")
  .on("click", function(e){
    // new event handler
  });
```

It's important to note that `$.on` and `$.off` are the preferred methods to use now as of jQuery 1.7. For further information on these methods, see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/), as well as [the blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) that announced them.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an `id`, and inside the first method, add the line:

```
getElementById("THE_ID_OF_THE_BUTTON").onclick = theOtherMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="btn" type="button" onclick="success();" value="click me!" />
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    function success(){
        alert('something');
        btn.onclick = otherFunction;
    }

    function otherFunction(){
        alert('Something new');
        // Now when you clik btn this code is going to be executed
        btn.onclick = success;
    }

</script>
```